# Currently a pharmacologist who wants to do statistics on their data and unsure how to proceed?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, biostatistics

I ran a dose-response experiment and obtained curves for 5 different animals; however, I am unsure of the best way to analyze this data. I have already log transformed my doses, but I was wondering if it be appropriate to use ANOVA to compare means of each dose? Or should I simply interpolate EC50/slope of the hill function and go from there? Unsure of where to move forwards from here

Comment: This needs more details, for ex: what is a dose-response experiment? Do you have repeated measures of the animals? Why did you transform your data? What is your goal - what are you trying to answer? What is a hill function?

Comment: A dose-response experiment is an experiment where a dose of a drug is administered in increasing amounts (e.g. 1 ug, 3 ug, 10 ug, 30 ug, 100 ug, for simplicity) in which a corresponding response to each dose is measured. Doses where transformed to normalize data at equal intervals. Each animal was subjected to the same dose range. Experimental goal is to find out what the drug effect is, alongside looking at parameters such as the dose that produces 50% of maximal response (EC50) and whether that differs between animals.

Comment: Hill function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)

Answer (score 0):

First, let me [quote](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40383882) [R.A. Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher):

> To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a *post mortem* examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of.

In other words, I doubt your data will suffice to answer your question. As I understand from your question, you have:

- five test animals
- each tested with $N$ different doses of a same substance
- and your measure some numerical response, which is expected to follow the Hill curve (a scaled and possibly shifted logistic curve)

From my knowledge of the field, your $N$, the number of different doses, is likely below 10, maybe even as low as 5.

It is unclear what your question is. Do you want to know:

- whether the animals all react differently to the substance, or
- whether any of the animals reacts "significantly" different from the other ones?

The first question cannot be answered with your data. You can, at best, answer the question whether they have reacted differently *in your experiment*, but the answer to that is going to be "yes", without doing any statistics, and even without seeing your data. No two animals are exactly equal. What you'd perhaps like to know is how the differences between the animals would compare to differences for any single animal, if you'd repeat the experiment. In that case you'd need to repeat your experiment multiple times with the same animal. But that's tricky, because the measurements wouldn't be independent anymore. Alternatively, you might ask whether different breeds of animals react differently. Then you would again need to repeat your experiment, but you'd be using a different animal in each run. You could use some measure of outcome, for example EC50, and use ANOVA to compare within-group (breed) variances with between-group (over all breeds) variances.

The second question goes in the direction of anomaly detection, but also here, the number of different animals is likely to be too low to detect an "anomaly", unless it's really large. The measurements for each animal ("the curve") can be represented as a single point in a $N$-dimensional space. For the animals who have similar responses, the points will be "close" to each other, and the one with a significantly different response will be an outlier, "far away". Now, the question is how to define "close" and "far away". You'll need to assume some probability distribution of the points (e.g. Gaussian), derive its parameters, $\mu$ and $\sigma$, from the data, and see whether one point is more than, say, $2 \cdot \sigma$ away from $\mu$. But, this is likely oversimplified, since your data are high-dimensional and there is no guarantee that your Gaussian is spherical (symmetrical in all directions). But, to estimate the whole covariance matrix you'd need more data.

You could do some dimensionality reduction. For example, computing the EC50 for each curve would make your data one-dimensional (with some loss of information). You can try the above anomaly detection on the EC50, but, again, I doubt 5 animals will suffice to detect any.

To summarise: You need more data!